# Better understanding of Ubuntu!

Tags: 16.04

I have been using Ubuntu for about 10-11 months now, and am familiar with the interface and basics. However, I have felt a complete understanding requires something more. Is there any great websites which covers the nuances, like how the OS interacts with the hardware, the working of the OS and its commands in general, the latest developments and such things in intermediate users lingo. For clarification, I already have working proficiency in it, so not looking for absolute beginners stuff, but for something in the intermediate level which would help me graduate to having some advanced skill sets. Anything would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Yes,  it is a practical problem that I am facing. I read  the rules and I believe it conforms with the requirements of this forum. Found one similar question asked 4 years back, but sadly the link provided in the answer no longer exists.

Comment: @N0rbert That thread you mentioned, as mentioned by many, is too broad. I am looking for specifics. Also, I have mentioned that I have used Ubuntu for quite some time. The answer there is for someone who is "Brand new to linux".

Comment: @pritmit This Q&A site is perfect for what you need. If you need to know a certain topic in Ubuntu, you can ask about it here and someone who knows the answer would answer it, just try to be as specific in your question as possible. Unfortunately, this question is currently too broad to be answered, but you are most welcome to post new questions and inquire about any details you want to know more about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very broad question so I am going to give you a broad answer;

The internet is your answer. We can't tell you what you need to know. You need to figure out what you want to know and try to find the answer online or ask it here. if you want to know how 'X' communicates with 'Y'. I would say; google it!. "how does X communicate with Y?"

Some keywords I found interesting things on are; Ubuntu tutorials, everything you need to know about ubuntu, becoming in expert in ubuntu. There is also many useful content on youtube. Other websites you can take a look at; Udemy, Skillshare, Coursera and Udacity.

You can also take a look at the answer from @N0rbert in this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029831/brand-new-to-linux-where-should-i-start?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks! "Udemy, skillshare, coursera and udacity".. I wanted to know places like these. like there are tonnes of materials out there, but i wanted to know the popular grounds for learning things. (and maybe some good obscure ones too!). For most documentations and books, I lack the patience to start from the absolute beginning and go through it, for i have some working knowledge, but on the other hand advanced documentations are too geekish for me. So i wanted some place for intermediate users. Would be great if you can point more such places. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I think I am at about the same level as you now. The things i mentioned can help you with a lot of things and increase your knowledge to some point. But at some point you do nonetheless have to start reading the documentation and books you have the lack of patience for at the moment, because that is the biggest source of information.

Comment: cool! thanks for having the patience to reply to such doubts. :)